# Unable to install working MariaDB

Tags: server, systemd, mariadb

I am starting a brand new install on a Proxmox Container (LXC, PVE 5.4).
Everything went fine except for MariaDB install.
I am using Ansible to install everything, but due to failure, I tried it manually.

At the end of install, it fails with a cool pink error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This error is from `phpmyadmin`, unable to connect, but in fact, the MariaDB service is unable to start.

> mariadb.service: Will not start SendSIGKILL=no service of type KillMode=control-group or mixed while processes exist
> mariadb.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Device or resource busy
> mariadb.service: Failed with result 'resources'. Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.

Everything is up-to-date and I am using official repository for MariaDB.

Comment: Have you tried all the steps here? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/

Comment: Which fix you think about ?

Comment: It seems there is no fix for me here...

Comment: If there are no errors/explanation in the mysql log then have you looked at the system log? Run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal window and then in another window try starting the service and see what (if any) errors or messages you might get when it tries and fails to start.

Comment: I shared you the only explanation I am getting, it sounds clear but illogical.
Jun 29 14:25:11 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Will not start SendSIGKILL=no service of type KillMode=control-group or mixed while processes exist
Jun 29 14:25:11 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Device or resource busy
Jun 29 14:25:11 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jun 29 14:25:11 web3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.

Comment: I tried a brand new install with nothing else than MariaDB and pre-requisite and it's not working. It seems it's a systemd update that breaks the mariadb service.

Jun 30 06:43:57 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Will not start SendSIGKILL=no service of type KillMode=control-group or mixed while processes exist
Jun 30 06:43:57 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Device or resource busy
Jun 30 06:43:57 web3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jun 30 06:43:57 web3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.4 database server.

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23050

Comment: Are you by any chance running multiple LXC containers? I'm getting the same error in a second container, the first one starts correctly. Both containers running Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04). I've tried starting containers in different order and it is always the first one to start that works and the second that doesn't. This issue mostly affects MariaDB but there are also other errors in journalctl -xe related to cgroups.

Comment: I am using several lxc container on same proxmox server 5 and this is the source of issue. From what I remember, setting SendSIGKILL=yes si enough as quick fix but upgrading proxmox is the good permanent fix. See the jira ticket in my previous comment.